# Настройка плагина Database Navigator в PyCharm. Ошибка: "Database information incomplete or invalid (host, port, database, file)"

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, pycharm

Хочу использовать плагин Database Navigator в PyCharm. Установил плагин из репозитория, рестартнул IDE, зашел в настройки и прописал такие параметры:

[image: db]

Но если нажать на кнопку Test Connection или Info, получаю ошибку: `Database information incomplete or invalid (host, port, database, file)`.

Как настроить этот плагин для работы с SQLite базой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас 2 *Database files*, но первый пустой. Удалите его (кликните на эту пустую строку и затем на `-` в правом столбце).

Comment: Спасибо. Думал, что первая строка это заголовок.

Comment: @typemoon, не стоит.